# I have a question regarding the proper usage of the word "nor"

Tags: word-choice

Is "...not legal advice, nor is it intended to be" the proper usage of "nor" in the prior partial statement?

Comment: Yes, there have been many similar threads on this topic of "nor" usage which involves coordination (in this case, probably coordination of main clauses).

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing wrong with the fragment.  Usually we would see:

**This is not legal advice and it is not intended to be.**

and in this case using **neither** is a bit awkward.